# Strong convexity composition rule with log sum exp

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose that $f_1(x), ..., f_n(x)$ are strongly convex functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, is it true that $\log\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(f_i(x)) \right)$ is also strongly convex?

Comment: Never mind, I managed to show it. It is indeed true.

Comment: I would suggest to add your own answer.